# javascript doing nothing

Tags: php, javascript

i am trying to make a finish time in a line of text update depending on the length of time selected in the drop down box relative to the start time.

so if the start time was 13:00 and the user selects 1 hour the finish time would update to 14:00

I dont have a  clue what i am doing right or wrong since i dont know the first thing about javascript.

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
         function changeText(){
            var option=document.getElementById('time').value;
               if(option=='30'){
                     document.getElementById('field').value='".date(strtotime("$finishtime + 30 minutes"))."';
                               }

              else if(option=='60'){
                     document.getElementById('field').value='".date(strtotime("$finishtime + 60 minutes"))."';
                               }
             }
  </script>
```

i dont seem to be getting any errors in the debugger and the script does nothing.

```
<a>Booking For ".$start." - </a><a id='field'>".$finishtime."</a><a> on ".$date."</a>

         <form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>
                 <a class='1'>Session Length</a>
                       <select name='time' id='time' onchange='changeText();'>
                             <option selected='selected'></option>
                             <option id='30' value='30'>30 mins</option>
                             <option id='60' value='60'>1 Hour</option>
                       </select>
```

Comment: What are you trying to use the <a...></a> tags for? Their main use is as links. Do you intend the user to click on them to perform some action? Or are you just using them as placeholders? Or....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
document.getElementById('field').text
```

instead of

```
 document.getElementById('field').value
```

Comment: I think you mean `.innerHTML`.

Comment: use this in if else conditions only